# Outlook notification subscription renew PATCH

Tags: php, outlook, synchronization

I am trying to renew notification subscription using below code.

```
        $token = json_decode($account->token, true);
        $newToken = json_decode($sync->refreshToken($token['refresh_token']), true);

        $headers = array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $newToken['access_token']
        );

        $url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/subscriptions/" . $token['events_hookId'];
        $res = $emailSync->runCurl($url, null, $headers, "PATCH");
        print_r($res);
    }
```

but its returning below error.

> {"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"An unexpected
>   'EndOfInput' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A
>   'StartObject' node was
>   expected."}}

Comment: my curl function https://gist.github.com/huzoorbux/25bb30c414fa6c7652dfba12f013524f

Comment: i missed body of my request `$data = '{
                                "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
                                "SubscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2019-04-06T17:17:45.9028722Z"
                            }';`

Issue resolved